Equality regarding score function
$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$I'm reading Bogetoft and Otto (2011) page 249 and this equality regarding the score function stumped me:
$$\Var\left[ -\Big(\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \beta^2}\Big)^{-1} \frac{\partial l}{\partial\beta}\right] = E\left[\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \beta^2}\right]^{-2} \Var\left[\frac{\partial l}{\partial \beta}\right]$$
How would one prove this? These are the properties of $\frac{\partial l}{\partial\beta}$ that I know of:
$$E\left[\frac{\partial l}{\partial\beta}\right] = 0$$
$$\Var\left[\frac{\partial l}{\partial \beta}\right] = -E\left[\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \beta^2}\right] = J$$
where $J$ is the information matrix.
The way its written makes it look like is a simple deduction but I guess I have some fundamental misconception about score functions. Any help appreciated.

$$\operatorname{Var} \left[ -\Big(\frac{\partial^2\ell}{\partial \beta^2}\Big)^{-1} \frac{\partial\ell}{\partial\beta}\right] = E\left[\frac{\partial^2\ell}{\partial \beta^2}\right]^{-2} \operatorname{Var} \left[\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \beta}\right]$$ If one were to treat $\partial^2\ell/\partial\beta^2$ as constant (i.e. not random) and $\partial \ell / \partial \beta$ as random, then this would make sense.
